# Getting nodes without edges

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a ton of nodes in a graph, and with some filters I am able to remove some edges by some condition, using `cy.remove(myCollection)`.

It happens sometimes that all edges to a node is removed and therefore its sitting alone without edges. Is there any way in Cytoscape to find these nodes without edges?

I was out in something like:

```
cy.nodes(/*:inside*/).filter(node => node.connectedEdges().size() === 0)
```

But this returns an empty collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution to this (so far) is that instead of manipulating whats inside the graph, I will do the filtering by setting an data property on the node/edge and style with `display: "none"` using the data property as a condition. Then this is working:

```
const nodesWithoutEdges = cy.nodes().filter(node => node.connectedEdges(":visible").size() === 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar problem: I had to remove nodes without edges from a graph. I solved it by using **[node.degree()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#node.degree)**  with a function that cycles through nodes of my graph and finds those with degree=0 (both indegree and outdegree, which means that the nodes have neither sources nor targets).

```
    `cy.nodes(function(element){
        if( element.isNode() && element.degree()<1){
            cy.remove(element)
        }
    })`
```

Hope it could be useful to fix your problem